# Secured WCF service without userPrincipalName

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, nettcpbinding

Is there a WCF configuration, when I don't have to specify `userPrincipalName` in the client and yet have some security?

My WCF service uses `netTcpBinding` and it's hosted in Windows Service. It works in closed intranet network though.

Thanks for help

Comment: One option is the certificate based WCF transport security (SSL/TLS) with `NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.Transport, true)`. That works well and fast enough. We use this for a closed intranet client/server system.

Answer (score 0):

As per the information from your question, I'm assuming that you are using Transport Security over TCP binding with Windows client credentials and the client provides the desired identity to authenticate itself. If this is the setup then you have three options for authenticating the client as per the following enum

```
public enum TcpClientCredentialType
{
 None,
 Windows,
 Certificate
}
```

In case of "Certificate" you will have to provide the X509 certificates for both service and clients. However, in case of "None", the client is anonymous but you still have to provide the service certificate for securing the transport.

In case you need additional authentication mechanisms, you can always implement your own logic or you can change the Transport security to Message Security, that provides you with additional authentication methods as per following enum

```
public enum MessageCredentialType
{
 None,
 Windows,
 UserName,
 Certificate,
 IssuedToken
}
```

Hope that helps!